# How to use Material Components Web sass in MeteorJS

Tags: meteor, sass, material-components

I want to use [**material design components for web**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web) inside my meteor application. Unfortunately when importing mdc from the npm package like this:

```
@import "{}/node_modules/material-components-web/material-components-web";
```

I get the following error:

```
While processing files with fourseven:scss (for target web.browser):
/client/stylesheets/Application.scss: Scss compiler error: File to import: @material/animation/mdc-animation not found in
file: {}/node_modules/material-components-web/material-components-web.scss
```

I guess this is due to the structure of mdc. The `material-components-web.scss` file imports all the single components, that are located in `node_modules/@material`, not inside `node_modules/material-components-web`.

I am using the [`fourseven:scss`](https://github.com/fourseven/meteor-scss/) package to compile sass in my meteor application.

How can I resolve/fix this issue?

Comment: I've requested an example on the github issue tracker: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/1040

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in your issue on github:

You need to create a scss-config.json file as described here: https://github.com/fourseven/meteor-scss#global-include-path

The content of that file would be:

```
{
  "includePaths": [
    "{}/node_modules/"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi this didn't work for me at all, did you have to do any extra step?

Comment: It's a long time ago since I was facing that issue and I can't remember exactly anymore how I did proceed. I think it was this same issue: https://github.com/fourseven/meteor-scss/issues/253
I worked on a fix but stopped work since I didn't need it anymore. So I'm sorry I can't help you more with this.